# Do SIC-POVM elements for $d=2$ sum up to the identity?

Tags: measurement, povm

I am studying [SIC-POVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIC-POVM) in dimension two and I want to check that the elements sum up to identity.

$$\begin{aligned}
& \left|\psi_1\right\rangle=|0\rangle \\
& \left|\psi_2\right\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|0\rangle+\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}|1\rangle \\
& \left|\psi_3\right\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|0\rangle+\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} e^{i \frac{2 \pi}{3}}|1\rangle \\
& \left|\psi_4\right\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|0\rangle+\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} e^{i \frac{4 \pi}{3}}|1\rangle
\end{aligned}$$

I calculated

$$
|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1|+|\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2|+|\psi_3\rangle\langle\psi_3|+|\psi_4\rangle\langle\psi_4|
$$

but the result was 2 times identity.

Do I need to divide them all by $\sqrt2$? Why this happened.

Comment: Please do not use images for text and equations. Images cannot be searched and copied and often don't render in a way consistent with text. You can use MathJax, see e.g. [here](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/tutorial-how-to-use-tex-mathjax-to-render-math-notation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You need to divide each projector by two. This is equivalent to dividing each state by $\sqrt2$.

Your calculation result is correct and can easily be corroborated by computing the trace
$$
\sum_{k=1}^4\mathrm{tr}(|\psi_k\rangle\langle\psi_k|)=\sum_{k=1}^4\langle\psi_k|\psi_k\rangle=4
$$
which is the same as $\mathrm{tr}(2I)=4$.

In order for the four projectors to form a POVM they should sum to identity, so you need to rescale them. Since you want a SIC-POVM you should rescale them equally which means dividing each projector by two.

Thus, your SIC-POVM will consist of $\frac12|\psi_k\rangle\langle\psi_k|$ for $k=1,2,3,4$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it. Now it is clear.